# C Scan user input (char), store it in variable and compare with strings

Tags: c

Hey I am trying to assign a string which is input by user to a variable and compare it afterwards.
But it always shows an error `initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast`

I would also rather use only one variable in which the input is stored and which I can compare with. But I cannot figure out how. Im new to C, so pointers and stuff are something really new

```
            char input;
            scanf("%c", &input);
            char *userInput = input;
            if (strcmp(userInput, "next") == 0)
```

Comment: Compare it with the *first character* in the string?

Comment: You need to read a string, not a single character. See the chapter called "string handling" in your C book. You cannot grasp strings before you understand arrays and pointers.

Comment: The error is exactly right. If you want to take the address of `input`, use the address-of operator `&`. As you already did. Do the same to assign to `userInput`.

Comment: @underscore_d: It’s passed into `strcmp`, though, which wouldn’t be right.

Comment: ah... sure, but one thing at a time I guess :-)

Comment: In the line `char *userInput = input;` you try to assign a single character (`char`) to a pointer (`char*`). This is wrong. You might want to use `scanf` with `%s` to read a string. And you need a `char[]` with a sufficient size instead of a `char*` to store data.

Comment: Thanks you all helped me a little. Now it works!

Comment: @akrun my comment was not directed to you at all but thanks